# Cassandra hugepages checklist

Tags: cassandra, jvm, cassandra-3.0, huge-pages

After reading about it, I decided to try enabling hugepages for cassandra. However, after setting something up, cassandra didn't started at all. I suspect that I missed some important setting necessary to actually allow cassandra to use hugepages, but I'm not sure what.

Specifically, I've done:

```
echo 112 >  /proc/sys/vm/hugetlb_shm_group
echo 2048 > /proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages
mount -t hugetlbfs hugetlbfs /dev/hugepages
```

with 112 being the cassandra group id, and added following to cassandra-env.sh:

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+UseLargePages -XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=2m -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch"
```

I'm using cassandra 3.11.3 on debian stretch.

I was reading following documentations:

- https://tobert.github.io/tldr/cassandra-java-huge-pages.html
- https://docs.openstack.org/nova/rocky/admin/huge-pages.html
- https://blog.pythian.com/performance-tuning-hugepages-in-linux/
- https://gist.github.com/tobert/c13803b905069b82e1fd

Note: While nothing is in /var/log/cassandra, I've found following in /var/lib/cassandra/hs_err_1557985546.log:

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 3992977408 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2643), pid=7022, tid=0x00007f10e1e02700
#
# JRE version:  (8.0_181-b13) (build )
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.181-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
.... some stack trace with just numbers ...
/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:        7657756 kB
MemFree:         2251340 kB
MemAvailable:    2198368 kB
Buffers:           33656 kB
Cached:           102892 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          1066784 kB
Inactive:          52664 kB
Active(anon):     983092 kB
Inactive(anon):      316 kB
Active(file):      83692 kB
Inactive(file):    52348 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:             19108 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        982900 kB
Mapped:            26556 kB
Shmem:               440 kB
Slab:              40420 kB
SReclaimable:      21728 kB
SUnreclaim:        18692 kB
KernelStack:        2976 kB
PageTables:         5312 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     1731724 kB
Committed_AS:    1227816 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
HugePages_Total:    2048
HugePages_Free:     2047
HugePages_Rsvd:      119
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       71680 kB
DirectMap2M:     7919616 kB
```

So it seems that the problem is that it is NOT using the HugePages and doesn't have enough non-huge-fied memory. But why?

Comment: when it's not starting, what it's in the `output.log` ?

Comment: I don't have any output.log. I do have system.log and there wasn't anything there. Not even in debug.log.

... wait. Found something. Too long for comment, I'll add it into question.

Comment: Are you sure that Java has started at all?

Comment: I'm sure /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java was executed.